# Excel chart showing wrong x-axis

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have table from which I draw an X-Y scatter plot. The data is based on column B and column D. I want it to depict percentages on both axes. I have three similar tables, but for one of them my chart is not working correctly. I want the x-axis to show the correct percentage scale.

I tried changing the column format between Percentage, Number and General. I tried creating a new figure from scratch.

The results are shown in the picture below. Also, I want it to NOT show data points where the cells are BLANK but instead it shows as zero in my chart along the y-axis.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that one of your "blank" cells actually contains a space or invalid character. See my example - this dataset works fine:

[image]

However, when I add space to cell B3 (highlighted), X-axis formatting is matching your screenshot. Also when cell D3 is a space, you will notice that additional dot was added to the chart:

[image]

I suggest checking all your blank cells and making sure they are truly blank - this should solve your both issues.

Hope it helps.